# Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords

Tags: visual-studio-code, bitbucket

Trying to apply the app password to existing repo from VS Code and just need clarity on a couple things

```
git remote set-url origin https://<Bitbucket_Username>:<App_Password>@bitbucket.org/<Repo_Name>.git
```

1. Do we need the username, app password & repo name enclosed in <> ?
2. Repo_Name I am unsure of, when looking at my full URL to clone on BitBucket it reads "git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/DCWorkspace/analytics.git", the "DC" I assume is my workspace name and the "analytics.git" my repo name so should I include both here or not?

   git remote set-url origin https://username:password@bitbucket.org/DC/analytics.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No
2. Used full path including workspace

Working so all good